# Calculator method

Tags: java, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator and have thought of an idea but do not know how to implement it in Java. I am trying to make a calculator which works when the user enters for example:

```
1+2-3/4 + 9 * 7= x
```

The answer i should get is 63

**PROBLEMS**

1. I have not been taught the method for the following and need help in these areas:

   Gathering the operators from every even character in the string from the left or every odd character from the right

   Gathering the numbers to be calculated on is every odd from the left or every even from the right.
2. I have currently made a Calculator program which works when you enter each digit and operator in a *separate input*. But I need to make it so that the user enters the equation in *one input* and not in *separate inputs*.

**This is my current program:**

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class Original_Calc
    {
    public static void main()throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double no,k=0,result;
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        int no1=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide)");
        String operand=br.readLine();
        String check="=";
        switch (operand)
        {
            case "+":
                    result=no1;
                    System.out.println("Enter number");
                    no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    result+=no;
                    System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                    operand=br.readLine();
                    k=check.compareTo(operand);
                    for(;;)
                    {
                        if(k!=0)
                        {
                            switch (operand)
                            {
                                case "+": 

                                        System.out.println("Enter number");
                                        no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                        result+=no;
                                        System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                        operand=br.readLine();
                                        k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                        break;
                                case "-":

                                         System.out.println("Enter number");
                                         no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                         result-=no;
                                         System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                         operand=br.readLine();
                                         k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                         break;
                                case "*":

                                         System.out.println("Enter number");
                                         no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                         result*=no;
                                         System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                         operand=br.readLine();
                                         k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                         break;
                                case "/":

                                         System.out.println("Enter number");
                                         no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                         result/=no;
                                         System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                         operand=br.readLine();
                                         k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                         break;
                                default:
                                        System.out.println("Please follow the instructions carefully");
                            }   
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("The result is "+result);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            case "-":
                    result=no1;
                    System.out.println("Enter number");
                    no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    result-=no;
                    System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                    operand=br.readLine();
                    k=check.compareTo(operand);
                    for(;;)
                    {
                        if(k!=0)
                        {
                            switch (operand)
                            {
                                case "+": 

                                        System.out.println("Enter number");
                                        no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                        result+=no;
                                        System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                        operand=br.readLine();
                                        k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                        break;
                                case "-":

                                         System.out.println("Enter number");
                                         no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                         result-=no;
                                         System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                         operand=br.readLine();
                                         k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                         break;
                                case "*":

                                         System.out.println("Enter number");
                                         no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                         result*=no;
                                         System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                         operand=br.readLine();
                                         k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                         break;
                                case "/":

                                         System.out.println("Enter number");
                                         no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                         result/=no;
                                         System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                         operand=br.readLine();
                                         k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                         break;
                                default:
                                        System.out.println("Please follow the instructions carefully");
                            }   
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("The result is "+result);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            case "*":
                    result=no1;
                    System.out.println("Enter number");
                    no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    result*=no;
                    System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                    operand=br.readLine();
                    k=check.compareTo(operand);
                    for(;;)
                    {
                        if(k!=0)
                        {
                            switch (operand)
                            {
                                case "+": 

                                        System.out.println("Enter number");
                                        no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                        result+=no;
                                        System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                        operand=br.readLine();
                                        k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                        break;
                                case "-":

                                         System.out.println("Enter number");
                                         no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                         result-=no;
                                         System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                         operand=br.readLine();
                                         k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                         break;
                                case "*":

                                         System.out.println("Enter number");
                                         no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                         result*=no;
                                         System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                         operand=br.readLine();
                                         k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                         break;
                                case "/":

                                         System.out.println("Enter number");
                                         no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                         result/=no;
                                         System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                         operand=br.readLine();
                                         k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                         break;
                                default:
                                        System.out.println("Please follow the instructions carefully");
                            }   
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("The result is "+result);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            case "/":
                    result=no1;
                    System.out.println("Enter number");
                    no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    result/=no;
                    System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                    operand=br.readLine();
                    k=check.compareTo(operand);
                    for(;;)
                    {
                        if(k!=0)
                        {
                            switch (operand)
                            {
                                case "+": 

                                        System.out.println("Enter number");
                                        no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                        result+=no;
                                        System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                        operand=br.readLine();
                                        k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                        break;
                                case "-":

                                         System.out.println("Enter number");
                                         no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                         result-=no;
                                         System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                         operand=br.readLine();
                                         k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                         break;
                                case "*":

                                         System.out.println("Enter number");
                                         no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                         result*=no;
                                         System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                         operand=br.readLine();
                                         k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                         break;
                                case "/":

                                         System.out.println("Enter number");
                                         no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                                         result/=no;
                                         System.out.println("Enter Operator (+ for add, - for subtract, * for multiply, / for divide or = for result)");
                                         operand=br.readLine();
                                         k=check.compareTo(operand);
                                         break;
                                default:
                                        System.out.println("Please follow the instructions carefully");
                            }   
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("The result is "+result);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            default:
                    System.out.println("Please follow the instructions carefully");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?? What result do you get?

Comment: I am trying to make a program where the user enters the equation in one line and not in separate inputs. Please read the question.

Comment: What answer do you expect from that input?

Comment: If your program works, then all you need to do is read the whole input in a single string and extract each character one at a time. For simplicity assume there are no spaces and you are dealing with single digit numbers. Use the substring method.

Comment: ^that was exactly what i was asking thanks.. What is substring method? I am very new to Java and haven't learnt that yet...

Comment: "*I have not been taught the method for the following*" : Do not expect to be taught how to code each and every possible application. You are taught to use programming tools and should use your brain to solve problems with those tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever heard of [postfix expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) or [prefix expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)? To evaluate answer correctly, you will have to convert the expression to postfix/prefix & evaluate it. As just by seeing infix, you might not be able to evaluate the expression correctly because of precedence order of operators. You can easily convert any mathematical expression to postfix/prefix & then code for evaluating posfix/prefix expression :)

**Edit:** Added tutorial links.

Converting infix to postfix tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vq-nUF0G4fI

Evaluating post/prefix expression: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MeRb_1bddWg

Comment: Read about it. They are pretty useful & involves stack.

Comment: For God sake this guy is new to Java and computer science.  Do not expect him to know this and even less to use it.

Comment: Added tutorial links. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

With regards to your question I think the best approach would be to write an algorithm to convert the input that you get from the user (Infix Notation) to something like Reverse Polish notation using Dijkstra's Shunting Yard Algorithm. This will allow you to take operator precedence into account.

Here is a video explaining it, it has a follow up video in C++ I think, however converting that to Java will be trivial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzVVjboyb0s

Here is the Wiki page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Comment: This is an overkill. He does not have to respect the priority of operators nor deal with parentheses. It looks like a Java 101 homework. Let's not cause more confusion.

Comment: @edTarik, why would OP not have to care about precedence? Why even parse equations for then - to get the wrong answer?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils As explained, this seems to be a Java 101 student who barely tries to get some simplistic code to work.